# Create a .pnp file from a directory

Tags: 2013, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I would like to source control an XML provisioning engine template and all of its required assets (js, css, html, etc.) in a Visual Studio project. When the time comes to provision the site, Id like to hand off a .pnp file that was generated from my project. I know I could apply the template to a site using the .xml, then extract a new .pnp from the site, but I would like to simplify this and eliminate the site from this process. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for this was to use `Convert-PnPFolderToProvisioningTemplate`. I wrote a simple build script that will run this on build.

[Convert-PnPFolderToProvisioningTemplate documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/Convert-PnPFolderToProvisioningTemplate.md)